# Evaluate expression

Tags: vb.net, object, express, evaluate

So, I have an object with some properties, like this: `Dim.d1, Dim.d2,...,Dim.d50`
that return strings. For example: `Dim.d1="Description A", Dim.d2="Description B",etc`.

What I want to do is to attribute these descriptions to the headers of a Gridview and for that I was thinking using indexes, like this pseudocode:

```
for i=0 until 49
e.Row.Cells[i].Text = Evaluate(Dim.d(i+1))
```

So, basically, I need a way to change the call to my object properties depending on the index, but I don't know if it is possible. When `index i=0`, call `Dim.d1`, when `index i=1` call `Dim.d2`, and so on until 50.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Dim` doesn't seem like it would be the best name to use for a variable in vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use methods in the `System.Reflection` namespace to do this. However, the answer is presented in order to answer the question - you should look at using some of the options suggested by other answerers e.g. use a `List(Of String)` or something similar.

Anyway, let's say you have a class:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Property d1 As String
    Public Property d2 As String
    Public Property d3 As String

End Class
```

And then, let's say you create an instance of that class and set its properties:

```
Dim obj As New Class1
obj.d1 = "Foo"
obj.d2 = "Bar"
obj.d3 = "Test"
```

If you then want to have a loop from 1 to 3, and access e.g. `d1`, `d2`, `d2` etc then this is where you use `Reflection`:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 3
    Dim info As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("d" & i)
    Dim val As String = info.GetValue(obj, Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
    Debug.Print(val.ToString)
Next
```

Will give you the output:

```
Foo
Bar
Test
```

Comment: Hello Robin! I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. But I need it for C#. I'll give it a try with the respective changes. There was a misunderstanding since my object is called Dim (short for Dimension) and has nothing to do with VB.net variable.

Comment: The key translations would be `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info = obj.GetType().GetProperty("d" + i);` and `string val = info.GetValue(obj, Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, null);`. Check out http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 3):

This is what Arrays or Lists are for!

```
var dim = new string[50];
dim[0] = "Description A";
dim[1] = "Description B";
..// etc

for(var i=0;i<49;i++)
{
    e.Row.Cells[i].Text = dim[i];
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid writing the code 50 times, because it can be more or less...For now I have 50 Descriptions but in the future can be more, so this have to be dynamic.

Comment: So use a `List<string>` and call `.Add("Description")`

Answer (score 0):

Like Jamiec already posted, use an Array or List.
Where do you description labels come from?

If you have your descriptions in a comma separated string, here is the vb.net code:

```
dim descriptions as String = "Description A,Description B,Description C"
dim myArray as String() = descriptions.Split(cchar(","))

for i as Integer = 1 To myArray.Length
    e.Row.Cells(i-1).Text = myArray(i)
Next
```

Comment: Hi Ulli. Yeah, I notice now that maybe I was not clear in my question. "Description A" or "Description B" were just examples (I can't put the real thing since is priveleged information of my company. But, descriptions are coming from linq, from a query in a database that returns a line, in this case, with 50 columns, each one containing the infamous descriptions. That's why I'm not sure how to really use List or Array here, at least without writing the 50 descriptions by hand. I think Reflection is the way to do it but have no idea how.